# What's a word that means things go from "worst to better"?

Tags: single-word-requests

This question refers to a life changing turn of events.

For example, “No one hired Stan for years because of a conviction of murder he didn't commit and did time for, but recently he won 100,000 dollars at the lottery.”

Comment: Does it have to be a single-word? Sometimes an expression or an idiom fits perfectly.

Comment: I'm looking to make a one word title for something I'm writing

Comment: And if there isn't one word? Your chances of getting better answers improves dramatically if you lift this restriction, which is not caused by lack of space.

Comment: In two words: **better fortune** or **fortune/luck revival**

Comment: Stan's luck has taken a turn for the better.

Comment: and now *everything's coming up roses*.

Comment: You could try to get away with hyphenating “Upward-bound” to get one word (and to distinguish it from the [USDOE program](http://www2.ed.gov/programs/trioupbound/index.html)), but I think the best one-word title for this story (although it doesn’t answer your question) would be “Finally.”

Answer (score 1):

I think the win at the Lottery represents  a  ***turning point*** in his life. The expression has usually a positive connotation:

> - a moment when the course of events is changed: *the turning point of his career*
> - an event marking a unique or important change of course or one on which important developments depend.

The Free Dictonary

If you need a single word *u-turn* or *turnaround*  may fit.

Answer (score 0):

Ascend might be the word I'm looking for,it means to rise from a lower level.

- Example:Ascended from poverty to great wealth

The Free Dictionary

Comment: So does *rebound*,  *upswing*, or *bounce back*.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want fireworks to go off in the readers' heads with a single word, maybe *improve* will do it?

> No one hired Stan for years because of a conviction of murder he didn't commit and did time for, but his prospects **improved** markedly after he won 100,000 dollars at the lottery.